# Add things to 'open xxx here' in browser

Tags: browser

Below is the typical right click menu you see in windows 10 if you right click somewhere in the browser.

[image]

I installed git bash and VS code and you can see I get to open the current folder in those programs. On a different PC with installing VS Code I forgot to check the box for this. So my other PC does not have the line `Open with Code'. And I want it, but I don't want to reinstall VS Code for such a small thing.

I also have a python script which does certain things in a folder. Currently this script is global executable .py . If I want to use it in a folder, I first must open git bash and run `gerber.py'.

I would like to add a line in this windows menu like: `gerber.py Here`.

How does one add/remove items to/from this menu? I want this to take effect in every folder

Comment: Its stored in the registry in HK_CLASSES_ROOT. If you find the extensions affected, export that regkey on a system that has the menu, and then import it on a system that doesn't, after a reboot it should be there too. Not 100% sure a reboot is required though. It may be that the extensions link to a global named field below. In that case, you could find: `.txt` has `TextFile`, and below there's a `TextFile` with the actual code. Then you must export both `.txt` and `TextFile`.

Comment: @LPChip, really an effective *answer*.

Answer (score 1):

Its stored in the registry in HK_CLASSES_ROOT.

If you find the extensions affected, export that regkey on a system that has the menu, and then import it on a system that doesn't, after a reboot it should be there too. Not 100% sure a reboot is required though.

It may be that the extensions link to a global named field below. In that case, you could find: `.txt` has `TextFile`, and below there's a `TextFile` with the actual code.

If that's the case, then you must export both `.txt` and `TextFile`.

A sidenote though, the `*` applies to every file, in case you want to hack something that is just always there on right-click.

Make sure you create a backup before import or alterations in case you break something and want to go back to a previous state. You can do that by right-clicking and choose export. It will export that key and every subkey.